# vue scss scope does not work for root element

Tags: vue.js, sass

I have a component with a b-modal on the root element.

```
<template>
  <b-modal ref="mymodal" modal-class="my-modal">
```

on the scss I define some margin

```
<style lang="scss">
  .my-modal {
    margin-top: 100px;
```

This works as expected, but if I scope my scss

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  .my-modal {
    margin-top: 100px;
```

it doesn't work, the child elements have all css applied but the root element doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

> With scoped, the parent component's styles will not leak into child
>   components. However, a child component's root node will be affected by
>   both the parent's scoped CSS and the child's scoped CSS. This is by
>   design so that the parent can style the child root element for layout
>   purposes.

So since the 'modal-class' will not be set on the child components root node, you have to use the deep selector (https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors)

```
/deep/ .my-modal {
    margin-top: 100px;
```